# Hibernate and Criteria API returns Object array instead of Tuple

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying out Criteria API and am facing a weird issue with Tuples.

I am building a query much similar to the one described here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-tuple

But for some reason the result list is actually `List<Object[]>` and not `List<Tuple>`, and so my code fails at runtime.
I can easily workaround the issue and change the iteration over the list so it works at runtime, but I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is the code for my query:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();

Root<Users> usersRoot = cq.from(Users.class);
Path<String> namePath = usersRoot.get(Users_.fullName);
Path<Integer> employeeIdPath = usersRoot.get(Users_.employeeId);
cq.multiselect(namePath, employeeIdPath);

List<Tuple> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (Tuple tuple : resultList) {
    names.add(tuple.get(namePath));
}
```

This code compiles properly, but I'm getting a `ClassCastException` when I reach the `for` loop: `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to javax.persistence.Tuple`

Debugging confirms that indeed the returned result list contains `Object[]` and not `Tuple`, thus breaking the API contract.

My hibernate maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This code is deployed as an EJB 3.1 application to a Weblogic 12.1.3 container, the underlying database is Oracle 12.

Comment: Code is correct, that is what Tuple is for. Raise a bug on your JPA provider

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and it works just fine. Check out [this test](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/criteria/TupleTest.java) on my GitHub repository:

```
doInJPA(entityManager -> {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();

    Root<BlogEntityProvider.Post> postRoot = cq.from(BlogEntityProvider.Post.class);
    Path<Long> idPath = postRoot.get("id");
    Path<String> titlePath = postRoot.get("title");
    cq.multiselect(idPath, titlePath);

    List<Tuple> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

    for (Tuple tuple : resultList) {
        Long id = tuple.get(idPath);
        String title = tuple.get(titlePath);
    }
});
```

This is with `5.0.3.Final`. If that's not working on `4.2.21` please add an issue on the [Hibernate Jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: I have the same problem with 5.0.4.FINAL. Will try running your test and report back. What DB did you use for the test? I'm thinking maybe the problem is somewhere in the Weblogic/Oracle DB setup I'm using.